# .htaccess RedirectMatch. Match for string except one word

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, redirect

I need help with a RedirectMatch Regex directive.

I need the following URL to be redirected as follow :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/category/category-title/(.+)(!?/page/)$ http://example.com/product/category-title/$1
```

The result I want is to redirect to specified product title except if word page is found :

http://example.com/category/category-title/some-product-title-here

redirects to

http://example.com/product/category-title/some-product-title-here

The following would not match : 
http://example.com/category/category-title/page/23

EDIT :

I have a redirect loop with the following rules :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/categorie/boulangerie-et-patisserie/((?!/page/).+)$ http://recyclageindustriel.com/produit/boulangerie-et-patisserie/$1

RedirectMatch 301 ^/produit/boulangerie-et-patisserie/page/(.*)$ http://recyclageindustriel.com/categorie/boulangerie-et-patisserie/page/$1
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your negative lookahead syntax is incorrect and it is placed wrongly also.

Try this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/categorie/boulangerie-et-patisserie/(?!page/)(.+)$ /produit/boulangerie-et-patisserie/$1

RedirectMatch 301 ^/produit/boulangerie-et-patisserie/page/(.*)$ /categorie/boulangerie-et-patisserie/page/$1
```

Correct negative lookahead syntax is `(?!page/)`.

Comment: Thanks, this is working great. Although, I have a redirect loop with an other rule : 

RedirectMatch 301 ^/product/category-title/page/(.*)$ http://example.com/category/category-title/page/$1

Comment: If you post complete .htaccess then I can probably check.

Comment: Thanks anubhava, I edited my question with the information.

Comment: Thanks a lot anubhava, this is the correct solution to my problem. I tried different regex but got lost at some point. This is very good !

Answer (score 0):

In

```
http://example.com/category/category-title/.htaccess
```

include the rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^page/
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://example.com/product/category-title/$1 [R=301]
```

This translates as:

***Only*** follow the next `RewriteRule`, **if** the requested URI **does not** begin with `page/`.